# Programmatically close modal sheet Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a window that needs to open another window as a model sheet. I have the following files:

- MainMenu.xib (Main window for program obviously)
- AppDelegate.m (This handles opening the Login.xib on applicationDidFinishLaunching)
- Login.xib (The window that is used as the modal sheet, contains 2 textFields and a button)
- LoginController.m (The processes the data that was filled out in the modal sheet)

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize loginScreen = _loginScreen;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Prompt user login credentials
    [self activateLoginScreen];
}

-(IBAction)activateLoginScreen {

    if (!_loginScreen)
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Login" owner:self];

    [NSApp beginSheet:self.loginScreen
       modalForWindow:[[NSApp delegate] window]
        modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:NULL
          contextInfo:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)closeLoginScreen:(id)sender {

    [NSApp endSheet:self.loginScreen];
    [self.loginScreen close];
    self.loginScreen = nil;
}
```

My LoginController.m:

```
#import "LoginController.h"

@implementation LoginController
@synthesize txtMnemonic, txtPassword;

- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {

    NSString *mnemonic = [txtMnemonic stringValue];
    NSString *password = [txtPassword stringValue];

    if ([mnemonic length] == 0 || [password length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Please provide username and/or password.");
    } else {

        // Call web service here

    }
}

@end
```

Also worth mentioning here that AppDelegate is the file owner of Login.xib.

My problem is that, I can open the modal window just fine when the app starts up. But how would I then close that window from within LoginController.m? And it can't be done with some button action. The button on that modal sheet is used to process the form. So after the form has been processed and everything has been verified, would I like to close the modal sheet. So basically call 'closeLoginScreen()' in AppDelegate.m from within LoginController.m

Comment: ignore my answer, thought this was ios

Answer (score 0):

From within your LoginController you can close the sheet using

```
[NSApp endSheet:[self window] returnCode:NSCancelButton]; //... or NSOKButton
```

Although not necessary, the normal practice is to provide a delegate to perform cleanup!

```
-(IBAction)activateLoginScreen {

if (!_loginScreen)
    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Login" owner:self];

[NSApp beginSheet:self.loginScreen
   modalForWindow:[[NSApp delegate] window]
    modalDelegate:self
   didEndSelector:@selector(mySheetWasClosed:returnCode:contextInfo:)
      contextInfo:NULL];
}
```

And your delegate function

```
- (void)mySheetWasClosed:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (returnCode==NSOKButton)
    {
        // all validations have been made by the sheet
    }
    [sheet orderOut:self];
    self.loginScreen = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although, when you say [self window], LoginController is not the file owner of the Login.xib... So I'm getting an error "No visible at interface for 'LoginController' declares the selector 'window'

Comment: [self window] is an example, just replace it for a valid pointer to the sheet (window) object (in your example that pointer seems to be self.loginScreen, but I'm not sure who is the owner of your interface).